# Mouse Does Not Move Automatically When Pressing Left Button

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm coding a C++ program that makes a certain movement with the mouse by itself when I press the left mouse button, it has F1, F2, F3 keys and each key has a different movement, and then I press the left mouse button to execute that movement , but what is happening is that I have to hold down the F1 key and the left mouse button at the same time for it to work, I wanted to press the F1 key just once and then just hold down the left mouse button !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "patterns.h"

#define getLen(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))

using namespace std;

typedef struct $ {
    string  name;
    long    **pattner;
    int     len;
    int     rpm;
}weapon_t;

    weapon_t *LoadWeapon(string name, long recoil[][2], int len, int rpm);
    float GetK(float dpi, float sensi);
    DWORD GetTime(float rpm);
    void ExecControl(weapon_t gun);

    float K;

int main()
{

    K = GetK(800, 0.95);

    weapon_t *ak47 = LoadWeapon("AK-47", ak47_pattern, getLen(ak47_pattern), 600);
    weapon_t *m4a4 = LoadWeapon("M4A4", m4a4_pattern, getLen(m4a4_pattern), 666);
    weapon_t *ump45 = LoadWeapon("UMP-45", ump45_pattern, getLen(ump45_pattern), 666);
    weapon_t* m4a1s = LoadWeapon("M4A1S", m4a1s_pattern, getLen(m4a1s_pattern), 600);
    weapon_t* famas = LoadWeapon("FAMAS", famas_pattern, getLen(famas_pattern), 600);

    while (true) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1)) {
            ExecControl(*ak47);
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F2)) {
            ExecControl(*m4a4);
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F3)) {
            ExecControl(*m4a1s);
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F4)) {
            ExecControl(*ump45);
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F5)) {
            ExecControl(*famas);
        }
        Sleep(150);
    }

    return 0;
}

void ExecControl(weapon_t gun) {
    system("cls");

    cout << "Weapon:\t" << gun.name << "\nShots:\t" << gun.len << "\nVelocity:\t" << gun.rpm << "\n\n\n";

    DWORD delay = GetTime(gun.rpm);

    int index = 0;

    while (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) && index != gun.len) {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, long(gun.pattner[index][0] * K), long(gun.pattner[index][1] * K), 0, 0);
        index++;
        Sleep(delay);
    }

    index = 0;
}

weapon_t *LoadWeapon(string name, long recoil[][2], int len, int rpm) {
    
    int i;

    weapon_t *gun = new weapon_t();

    gun->name = name;
    gun->len = len;
    gun->rpm = rpm;

    gun->pattner = new long*[len];
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        gun->pattner[i] = new long[2];
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        gun->pattner[i][0] = recoil[i][0];
        gun->pattner[i][1] = recoil[i][1];
    }

    return gun;
}

float GetK(float dpi, float sensi) {
    return (1140 / (dpi*sensi));
}

DWORD GetTime(float rpm) {
    return DWORD((60 / rpm) * 1000);
}
```

Comment: So.... pick an initial state. When any of the F* buttons are pressed, update the state. When the button is clicked, perform whichever action your current state indicates to be appropriate.

Comment: I just want to press the F1 key and then the movement will be done automatically when I press the left mouse button, at the moment I have to hold down F1 and the left mouse button together to work, I just want to press F1 once and the movement be done when I press the left mouse button

Comment: Yes I know. That's why I told you how to do it. Think of keypresses and mouse-clicks as events. You get told about them afterwards. If someone hits an F* button, they've asked to change modes. If someone clicks the mouse, they've asked to perform the current mode's action. Keeping track of the current mode (set with an F* key) allows you to respond to a single click without checking the state of an F* key at the same time - you already know which was pressed last time and thus, which action should be performed.

Comment: I did but it was not cool, how did you leave the code?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code is looking at the mouse left button only *while* any <kbd>F1</kbd>..<kbd>F5</kbd> key is currently held down, and then you are not looking at the keyboard again until the left button is released or the current `gun` is exhausted.

You need a different approach, such as a state machine.  Keep track of the current `gun` that is equipped at any given time.  On each iteration of the main loop, check for state changes first (ie, check if any <kbd>F1</kbd>..<kbd>F5</kbd> key is held down, and if so then equip the associated `gun`), and then act on the current state (ie, regardless of the keyboard state, if the left button is down, and a `gun` is equipped, then advance the `gun` to its next position).  Let the loop handle the repetitive work for you. This will allow you to check the keyboard for gun changes while the left button is held down.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "patterns.h"

#define getLen(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))

using namespace std;

typedef struct $ {
    string  name;
    long    **pattner;
    int     len;
    int     rpm;
}weapon_t;

weapon_t* LoadWeapon(string name, long recoil[][2], int len, int rpm);
float GetK(float dpi, float sensi);
DWORD GetTime(float rpm);
float K = GetK(800, 0.95);

int main()
{

    weapon_t *ak47 = LoadWeapon("AK-47", ak47_pattern, getLen(ak47_pattern), 600);
    weapon_t *m4a4 = LoadWeapon("M4A4", m4a4_pattern, getLen(m4a4_pattern), 666);
    weapon_t *ump45 = LoadWeapon("UMP-45", ump45_pattern, getLen(ump45_pattern), 666);
    weapon_t *m4a1s = LoadWeapon("M4A1S", m4a1s_pattern, getLen(m4a1s_pattern), 600);
    weapon_t *famas = LoadWeapon("FAMAS", famas_pattern, getLen(famas_pattern), 600);

    weapon_t* guns[] = {ak47, m4a4, m4a1s, ump45, famas};
    int gun_keys[] = {VK_F1, VK_F2, VK_F3, VK_F4, VK_F5};
    weapon_t *gun = nullptr;
    int gun_index = -1;
    DWORD gun_delay = 150;
    bool is_mouse_down = false;

    while (true) {

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(gun_key[i]) && (gun != guns[i])) {
                gun = guns[i];

                system("cls");

                cout << "Weapon:\t" << gun->name << "\nShots:\t" << gun->len << "\nVelocity:\t" << gun->rpm << "\n\n\n";

                gun_delay = GetTime(gun->rpm);
                gun_index = 0;

                break;
            }
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0) {
            if (!is_mouse_down) {
                is_mouse_down = true;
                if (gun != nullptr)
                    gun_index = 0;
            }
            if (gun != nullptr  && gun_index != gun->len) {
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, long(gun->pattner[gun_index][0] * K), long(gun->pattner[gun_index][1] * K), 0, 0);
                ++gun_index;
                Sleep(gun_delay);
                continue;
            }
        }
        else    
            is_mouse_down = false;

        Sleep(150);
    }

    return 0;
}

weapon_t* LoadWeapon(string name, long recoil[][2], int len, int rpm) {

    weapon_t *gun = new weapon_t();

    gun->name = name;
    gun->len = len;
    gun->rpm = rpm;

    gun->pattner = new long*[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        gun->pattner[i] = new long[2];
        gun->pattner[i][0] = recoil[i][0];
        gun->pattner[i][1] = recoil[i][1];
    }

    return gun;
}

float GetK(float dpi, float sensi) {
    return (1140 / (dpi*sensi));
}

DWORD GetTime(float rpm) {
    return DWORD((60 / rpm) * 1000);
}
```

Comment: I put my complete code, I had put only a part, take a look again pls

Comment: @user17919505 "*I put my complete code*" - that was not necessary, none of the code you added changes what I said.  But I have updated my answer to show my suggested code inside the context of your code.

Comment: I want every time I press the left mouse button the movement works, but if I stop pressing at some point and press again the movement starts again from the beginning. How do I do that ?

Comment: @user17919505 you need to keep track of the mouse state so you can detect when it changes. I have updated my example to show this.

Comment: I have no words to describe how much you helped me, thank you very much from the heart, do you have discord?

Comment: @user17919505 "*do you have discord?*" - no